# How to cleanse data in multiple tables in a database?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

I would like some ideas on the following problem.

### The System

In a customer-centric system, the `Customer_id` is a right-aligned 9-digit code with 7 leading spaces.
A valid entry would be '       `000000399`'.

There is a master `CUSTOMERS` table and nearly 80 detail tables.
The master table `CUSTOMERS` has multiple records for each `Customer_id` and uses columns `Start_date`, `End_date` for record history.
The End_date is initially '`9999`             ' and is updated to the `Start_date` of a new record whenever a new record for an existing `Customer_id` is inserted.

An example follows. The first record for Customer_id '       `000000399`' would be:

+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      Cust_id       |     Start_date      |      End_date       |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| '       000000399' | '20100225210300000' | '9999             ' |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

Lets assume that a new record in inserted at `2010-03-03 12:37:33,000`
The new record should have an End_date of '9999' and the previous record's End_date should be updated with the new Start_date.
The records of this Customer_id should be:

+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      Cust_id       |     Start_date      |      End_date       |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| '       000000399' | '20100225210300000' | '20100303123733000' |
| '       000000399' | '20100303123733000' | '9999             ' |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

This pattern is followed in the master and the detail tables that use a Start_date and an End_date columns.

The Problem
At some point in time `Customer_ids` started being inserted in wrong formats. You can find the following formats for the same Customer.

```
'       000000399'

'000000399       '

' 000000399      '
```

The problem is that these `Customer_ids` are treated as different Customers from the system, so they maintain their own chains of `Start_date` and `End_date`.
We end up having the following records for the customer (sorted by `Start_date`).

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Cust_id | New_Cust_id | Start_date        | End_date          | New_End_date      |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20100225210300000 | 20100303123733000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20100303123733000 | 20110127001826000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20110127001826000 | 20110129001706000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20110129001706000 | 20120309001920000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20120309001920000 | 20120406001926000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20120406001926000 | 20120524001910000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20120524001910000 | 20130129180350000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20130129180350000 | 20131212153024000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20131212153024000 | 20150424184238000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20150424184238000 | 20160222184547000 | 20151103095530339 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     | 399         | 20151103095530339 | 20180714105242000 | 20160222184547000 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20160222184547000 | 20180911143426000 | 20180714105242000 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     | 399         | 20180714105242000 | 9999              | 20180911143426000 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20180911143426000 | 9999              |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

### The Challenge

We face the challenge of cleaning the data so that there are no Customer_ids deviations and that current data keep their integrity and consistency.
In the above example the solution is to inject the records with the faulty `Customer_ids` in the correct position (`Start_date/End_date`) and with the correct `Customer_id` format.
Lets add some new columns for the columns that need to get updated.

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Cust_id | New_Cust_id | Start_date        | End_date          | New_End_date      |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20100225210300000 | 20100303123733000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20100303123733000 | 20110127001826000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20110127001826000 | 20110129001706000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20110129001706000 | 20120309001920000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20120309001920000 | 20120406001926000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20120406001926000 | 20120524001910000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20120524001910000 | 20130129180350000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20130129180350000 | 20131212153024000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20131212153024000 | 20150424184238000 |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20150424184238000 | 20160222184547000 | 20151103095530339 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     | 399         | 20151103095530339 | 20180714105242000 | 20160222184547000 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20160222184547000 | 20180911143426000 | 20180714105242000 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     | 399         | 20180714105242000 | 9999              | 20180911143426000 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 399     |             | 20180911143426000 | 9999              |                   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

An image counts for a thousand words, so this is what it should look like:
[records injected in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGgzw.png)

Simply put, whenever the following record has a different Customer_id format, the End date of the previous record must be updated to the value of the inserted Start_date.
Of course the faulty Customer_id must also be updated to the right format (right-aligned).

So the final state of the previous data should look like:
[records updated as needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBdDa.png)
Updated data shows in Green color.

### The solution

I am looking for a way to clean the data. I have some initial thoughts but I would like to hear some suggestions.
The database is minimally indexed, most tables are  heaps, there are no referential keys. 
Some numbers:
    - 32M Customer records
    - 4M unique `Customer_ids`
    - 150K faulty records (wrong Customer_id format)
    - 80 tables with faulty records
    - 132M records is the biggest table

The limitations
    - Minimal downtime
    - New records are coming to the database (hopefully with the correct format)

I am currently working on writing a procedure that will do the following:

1. Select each distinct `Customer_id` from the `CUSTOMERS` table that has faulty records.
2. Start a new Transaction

   a. Create a temporary Table with all the corresponding records from
   table `CUSTOMERS` for this `Customer_id` (in all formats)

   - i. Sort these records on the temporary table according to the
     Start_date
   - ii. Update the End_date whenever required
   - iii. Update the faulty Customer_id
   - iv. Update the altered records on the `CUSTOMERS` table - by deleting all related records and inserting the  updated ones from the
     temporary table, or- by updating the existing related records

   b. Continue to the next (detail) table and create a new temporary table
           i. Repeat steps i-iv
3. Commit the transaction when the records for the current `Customer_id` are updated in all 80 detail tables.
4. Loop to the next `Customer_id` and repeat steps 1-3
5. Pray that everything will work according to plan…

Please share your thoughts.

PS. Sorry for the lengthy post :)

Comment: Please format your question. As it stand it is unreadable. Do not use images with tables inside them, use text to represent data. Use [this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to format tables.

Comment: Try to supply only critical info and ask short and specific questions. As it stands now it's: "I have a big problem with a lot of data, please fix it." I can fix these kind of things, however this is not to place for me to place invoices and such.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will try to rephrase the question.

Comment: Please don't post sample data as ascii tables. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)